# PHP - Rename files in directory after sorting them alphabetically

Tags: php, file, sorting, rename

I have this weird problem.

I have my files called 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg.

Now, I want people to be able to sort them, so I thought, if you want 3 to become 2 for exemple, all you have to do rename 3.jpg ==> 1b.jpg. This places him between 1 and 2!

Now just rename all files in the folder, and voila!
This, however, doesn't seem to work...

My code is:

```
// Part 1

$fileUp = $_POST['imageURL'];
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$fileUp;
$fileParts = pathinfo($fileUp);
$fileName = $fileParts['filename'];
$fileExt = $fileParts['extension'];
$fileFolder = $fileParts['dirname'];
$newName = $fileName - 2;
$newFullName = $newName . 'b.' . $fileExt;

$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$fileFolder.'/';

rename($url, $directory.$newFullName);

// Part 2

$dirFiles = array();
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {  
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $dirFiles[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

sort($dirFiles);
$i = 1;
foreach($dirFiles as $file)
{
    $fileParts = pathinfo($file);
    $fileExt = $fileParts['extension'];
    $newName = $i . '.' . $fileExt;
    rename($directory.$file, $directory.$newName);
    $i++;
}
```

Part 1 essentially renames the file to be upped. This works!
However, if I then reload the files using readdir, this image isn't where it's supposed to be (often at the end).

So Part 2 is about renaming all the files.
However, when I enable part 2, the image before the image to be upped disappears!

So for exemple, if I have "1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg", and I want to up 2.jpg, I end up with:
"2.jpg, 3.jpg" (2 and 3 haven't changed their names, 1.jpg simply disappeared...)

All help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend that way to sort images, it is both inefficient and as I understand, if people keep sorting, you will end up with long and clumsy file names.
Do you have access to a database? You could have a table there which maps indexes to file names which allow you to sort by changing the indexes of a table entry.

Comment: Yes I do have access to a database, but this does just seemed the easier way. Btw, users are only allowed to upload 10 images, so it won't be that long in the end...

But ok, I see the point.
The files are actually uploaded by users, each one having their own directory.
Any suggestion how to deal with people uploading files with potentially incorrect characters in the filenames (brackets, spaces...)?

Comment: This could be a solution:
$remove_these = array(' ','`','"','\'','\\','/');
$newname = str_replace($remove_these, '', $_FILES['image']['name']);